# Can I read a value from a textbox control using PHP

Tags: php, html

If I have a text box on a php page, can I read that value using PHP without POSTING the form?

Thanks and Regards

Abishek R Srikaanth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If you want to do this, you will need to use JavaScript.

Vanilla JavaScript:
`alert(document.getElementById('textbox_id').value);`

jQuery:
`alert($('#textbox_id').val());`

Comment: well, I have that on an alert, but how to I get that to assign it to a variable in PHP?

Comment: You cannot, not without POST'ing. You could use JavaScript to call an asynchronous POST to another PHP page. If that's something you're interested in, I recommended jQuery and using it's POST method: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: @Abishek R Srikaanth you're lacking some fundamental knowledge of client/server relationship. Please read http 1.1 specifications in regards to HTTP Request POST, HTTP Request GET, additionally DOM/HTML/Javascript is client side parsing/processing (normally) and PHP is server side.

Comment: Well, I tried that and I am able to that and echo it on another PHP to get it back again on the success of $post. Well, what I am exactly trying to do is to get the data of the localstorage in HTML 5 from PHP

Comment: @Abi: You can't.  It's called **Local** storage.  You need to use AJAX.

Answer (score 3):

No. You either need to `HTTP Request POST` or `HTTP Request GET` to a PHP script. Or you can use Javascript or a Javascript library like jQuery to get the contents of the form field.

Comment: "with PHP"? That's an unfortunate phrasing.

Answer (score 1):

No. Definitely not.

Once the php output of server is complete, it sends out the total result to client machine and client machine parse it and play with it. after receiving data from server the connection between server and client is broked.

Since PHP runs in server and connection with server is broken so no way of such things.

But if we again pass information to server by posting for or use javascript ajax request then again it establishes connection with server and passes value. so there we can do it now.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't make any sense.
PHP only runs when you POST the form.

You may be looking for AJAX.

Answer (score -1):

Try using AJAX:

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Comment: That's not at all what he's asking for.

Comment: I wish I could -1 this again for mentioning W3Schools.